# JsDoc and WebStorm: Refer to exports

Tags: javascript, webstorm, intellisense, commonjs, jsdoc

I have a module like this:

```
/**
 * Do something with target. A bunch of these methods
 * @param target
 */
function doJob(target) {
    target.something = 'value';
}

module.exports = {
    doJob
};
```

WebStorm correctly recognizes that `doJob` is exported by this module, and gives nice intellisense.

Now I want to add facility so that I can bind all exported methods with a target.

```
module.exports = {
    doJob
};

const oldExports = Object.assign({}, module.exports);
module.exports.bind = function (target) {
    const newExports = {};
    for (var key in oldExports) {
        newExports[key] = oldExports[key].bind(null, target);
    }
    return newExports;
};
```

The idea is that consumers can get normal exports and use functions in a procedural style, or they can get the same set of functions, bound to their local `target`.

My problem is now, how do I tell WebStorm (using JsDoc) that the return value of `bind()` function is the same thing as `module.exports`?

Things I've tried:

- `@returns {module.exports}`
- `@returns {exports}`
- Declare `@module` at top, then `@returns` that symbol
- `@alias` - this unfortunately seem to completely take over the symbol, so now I no longer have anything at `module.exports`

I realize this is not the end of the world. But I feel like I am sooooo close to getting everything to fit together, it's driving me crazy.

Any idea what's the proper way to do this in JsDoc, with the added benefit that WebStorm / PhpStorm will know how to work with it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got it.

```
function doJob(target) {
    target.something = 'value';
}

class JobsModule {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, /** @lends {JobsModule.prototype} */ {
            doJob,
            // other exports go here
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new JobsModule();

/**
 * @return {JobsModule}
 */
module.exports.bind = function (target) {
    const newExports = {};
    for (var key in new JobsModule()) {
        newExports[key] = oldExports[key].bind(null, target);
    }
    return newExports;
};
```

Declare everything as a class, then just create it whenever you want it used. Not efficient, but probably not a big deal.